# Avoid certain combinations on a Math.random() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have to list of words:

```
<div class="first-word-list">
  <span>apple</span>
  <span>sea</span>
  <span>ship</span>
</div>

<div class="second-word-list">
  <span>duck</span>
  <span>tale</span>
  <span>jewelry</span>
</div>
```

the client can add any word to these list so it's not only going to be these 6 words.
I'm using a function that when on `click` event, it changes the word creating a combination between these two lists on this structure:

```
<div class="first-word"></div><div class="second-word"></div>

$('.first-word').click(function(){
  $('.first-word').text($(".first-word-list span").eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*firstWordLength)).text());
});

$('.second-word').click(function(){
  $('.second-word').text($(".second-word-list span").eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*firstWordLength)).text());
});
```

So, if the user clicks on `.first-word` and on `.second-word` it displays this:

```
<div class="first-word">sea</div><div class="second-word">tale</div>
```

but lets say I want to block/avoid to display the combination of `ship` and `jewelry`. Since I'm using a random function and like I wrote before, the word list will grow I need a way to control which words combinations won't be shown. Any idea how to do this?

**Update**
The client will write the banned combinations on two new custom fields which will output on a new list like this:

```
<div class="banned-combinations">
   <div><span>ship</span><span>jewelry</span></div>
   <div><span>apple</span><span>duck</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could maintain an array holding the banned combinations, and then check for any matches when the selections have been made.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can the array be created dynamically and how can I check the matches? I'm pulling the words from two custom fields (first_word and second_word) in Wordpress.

Comment: It could be created dynamically, but how can you work out the words which should not be allowed in that way? Surely you'd have to know before hand...?

Comment: Yeah, I'll give the client a new custom field in Wordpress where he can put the banned combinations. Will it work with only one field that outputs the banned combination?

Comment: Please edit the question and add information on how the banned combinations will be (made) available.

Comment: Would using a dictionary be out of the question? like having `var bannedOptions = { 'ship': { 'jewelry': true } }`? so that way if you did say like `if(bannedOptions[word1] != null && bannedOptions[word1][word2]) { /* invalid option */ } else { /* valid option */}`?

Comment: @trincot I've updated the question with how the banned combinations will be made.

Comment: @codek, I still think that behavior is underspecified. IMHO, the most important thing is that the words from 2 lists are generated independently. So assume that the first list contains `a` and `b`; the second list contains `1` and `2`; and that combination `a1` is prohibited. Now assume that current selection is `a2` and the user clicks on the second button. Is is true that `a2` is still the only valid output? Or can we switch to `b1, for example`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet that allows you to dynamically add words to either list, and to select words from those lists in order to mark them as forbidden combinations. Once you have everything entered as you want to have it, you can click the two random words to have them replaced by a new random word (which *could* be just the same word again), taking into account the forbidden combinations:

```js
// Allow adding words to either word list:
$(".add-word").on("change keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which && e.which != 13) return;
    $(this).before($("<span>").text($(this).val()));
    $(this).val('');
});

// Allow selecting words by clicking them
$(".word-list").on("click", "span", function () {
    $(".selected", $(this).parent()).removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    showButton();
});

// Allow forbidding pairs of selected words:
$("#forbid").click(function () {
    $(".forbidden").append(
        $("<div>").append(
            $(".selected").removeClass("selected").clone(),
            $("<button>").addClass("del").text("Del")
        )
    );
    showButton();
});

// Remove forbidden pair:
$(document).on("click", ".del", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

// Hide/show button depending on whether we have enough selected words:
function showButton() {
    $("#forbid").toggle($(".selected").length == 2);
}

// Main algorithm:
$(".random-word").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index(".random-word");
    // Get word that is not clicked:
    var otherword = $(".random-word").eq(1-index).text();
    // Get all words from corresponding list
    var words = $("span", $(".word-list").eq(index)).map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    // Get list of forbidden words that are linked with the other (non-clicked) word
    var forbidden = $('.forbidden div').filter(function () {
        return $('span', this).eq(1-index).text() == otherword;
    }).map(function () {
        return $('span', this).eq(index).text();
    }).get();
    // Derive the list of allowed words, taking all words, filtering out what is forbidden
    var allowed = words.filter(function (txt) {
        return forbidden.indexOf(txt) == -1;
    });
    // Pick a random from these allowed words:
    $(this).text(allowed.length 
        ? allowed[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)]
        : "(none)"
    );
});

showButton();

// *** Upon special request following was added ***
// Algorithm for choosing random pair in one go:
$("#choose").click(function () {
    // Get all words from both lists
    var words = $(".word-list").get().map(function (list) {
        return $("span", list).get().map(function (span) {
            return $(span).text();
        });
    });
    // Get list of forbidden words pairs
    var forbidden = $('.forbidden div').get().map(function (div) {
        return $('span', div).get().map(function (span) {
            return $(span).text();
        });
    });
    // Derive the list of allowed pairs, taking all pairs, filtering out what is forbidden
    var allowed = words[0].reduce(function (pairs, word) {
        // Get list of forbidden second words, given the first word
        var exclude = forbidden.filter(function(pair) {
            return pair[0] == word;
        }).map(function (pair) {
            return pair[1]; // extract second word of the pair
        });
        // Filter all second words, excluding those that are forbidden pairs with first word.
        return pairs.concat(words[1].filter(function (word2) {
            return exclude.indexOf(word2) == -1;
        }).map(function (word2) {
            return [word, word2];
        }));
    }, []);
    // Pick a random pair from these allowed pairs:
    var randomPair = allowed.length 
        ? allowed[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)]
        : ["(none)", "(none)"];
    // Display the pair
    $(".random-word").each(function (i) {
        $(this).text(randomPair[i]);
    });
});
```

```css
span {margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px}
span.selected {background-color: yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>First word list:</b>
<div class="word-list">
  <span>apple</span>
  <span>sea</span>
  <span>ship</span>
  <input class="add-word" size=10>
</div>
<b>Second word list:</b>
<div class="word-list">
  <span>duck</span>
  <span>tale</span>
  <span>jewelry</span>
  <input class="add-word" size=10>
</div>
<button id="forbid">Add combination as forbidden</button><br>
<b>Forbidden combinations:</b>
<div class="forbidden">
</div>
<b>Random Pair (click a word to reselect a random, allowed word):</b>
<div class="random-word">sea</div><div class="random-word">tale</div>
<button id="choose">Random Pick Both</button>
```

Comment: thanks trincot, I'll check it out. I've updated the question showing how the banned combinations will be made.

Comment: OK, that is just about how I had used it in my answer, so I'll leave it like it is.

Comment: this works perfect! Let's say I have a `button` that changes both words at same time (filtering out the forbidden combinations), how can I apply this main algorithm to the `button`?

Comment: I added a button in HTML code, with JS for selecting both values as a random pair.

Comment: this is the perfect solution. Thank you very much! I'll give the bounty as soon as it is available.

Comment: I've checked and gave the bounty to the wrong answer, do you know how to contact a moderator to change it? sorry :/

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate. You had a warning before awarding it that it cannot be undone. You could try to "flag"  my answer (if you have the link below it), and explain your case. An admin will process it. Otherwise you could ask what can be done on meta.stackoverflow.com, but it has been [asked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310234/gave-bounty-to-wrong-answer-reversing-bounty).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to handle adding banned options but if everything needs to be dynamic then you could always utilize a dictionary (object).

```
var bannedOptions = { 
    'ship': { 
        'jewelry': true 
    }
};
```

When you go to check if an option is valid you can simply do something like:

```
// Here I'm using truthy checks,you can always add a != null 
// if you want false or something to be a valid value
if(bannedOptions[word1] && bannedOptions[word1][word2]) {
    // It's invalid
} else {
    // Valid
}
```

When you want to add a new invalid option you could

```
if(!bannedOptions[newWord]) bannedOptions[newWord] = {};
bannedOptions[newWord][invalidWord] = true;
```

If you wanted to remove an invalid option you could do:

```
bannedOptions[word1][word2] = false;
```

or

```
delete bannedOptions[word1][word2];
```

Using a dictionary allows you to have super fast checks when you want to see if a combination is invalid.

It's super dynamic so you don't have to worry about indices or anything because the words themselves are keys... and as long as the word is accessed as a string you can have symbols like `-`,`'`,`/`, etc. in the words.

Comment: thanks Patrick, I'll check it out this solution. I've updated the question showing how the banned combinations will be made.